# SVN ignoring files not listed in svn:ignore

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svnignore

My svn:global-ignore and svn:ignore files previously had *.dll and *.pdb. For my current work, I need them to be part of the repository.

Therefore, I have edited my svn:global-ignore and svn:ignore files to not exclude any *.dll and *.pdb files. However, when I try to add these files, they are still ignored and does not show up in svn add .

Is there any other place that I should be looking at?

Answer (score 0):

Settings dialog, first page (General).
There's an edit box named `Global ignore pattern`.